# How to prepare collection for regular class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm just after reading of collections. A lot of discussions on that forum people reflect answers different way. However many opinions are different and there is not very enough clear output of it to me. Therefore I would like to take a chance and ask you to present examples for four of my scenarios i prepared - how you would prepare your collections in specific situation. Main target is to understand in which situations better to create separate class for the collection and in which situations it's good to keep it in same class without creating separate one just for collection.  Notice that scenarios are made by me so if there is other scenario good to have you welcome to present. I am sure that topic would be helpful for a lot of community asking a lot of it.

Let's assume we have following class to be used for our collection:

```
class Player
{
    Private string Name;
    Private string Age;
    Private EnumType PlayPosition;  //e.g center, back etc.
}
```

**Now consider situations I prepared**

**1st scenario:**

Just collection of Players with basic features for it like loop through them, add/delete/get all

**2nd scenario:**

Just like in 1st scenarion but as additional in add method to check whether such player Name already not exist in collection before add

**3rd scenario:**

Collection of players with all as in 2nd scenario but also with possibility of Sort them by either Name, Age or both and Compare

**4th scenario:**

To have both list of players and dictionary of players - in some cases sometime i need just a list and sometime a dictionary

Comment: So, what's really your question?

Comment: When do you "create separate class for the collection"? Never. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Separate class for collectios e.g class Player {} and spearate class for it: class Players {} which would inherit from either IList/ICollection etc / or not inherit but keep a list object as property and put all methods ther like add/get count..

Comment: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: You are (still) looking for some set of magic criteria for handling collections and there simply is none.  For the conditions listed, all could be handled just having a player collection flying around.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134262/discussion-on-question-by-arie-how-to-prepare-collection-for-regular-class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), given:

```
public static HashSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
```

Case 1:

```
Players.Add(new Player { Age = 98 });
```

Case 2:

You could override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to check whether `Name` already exists, then `Add` will take care of that for you.

Case 3 (what I understand):

```
var orderedPlayers = Players.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Case 4 (what I undestand):

```
var dictionaryPlayers = Players.ToDictionary(x => x.Age);
```

Comment: @Arie you could have a class that inherits from `HashSet<Player>`. Also, why not LinQ?

Comment: @Arie - That is really a poor reason. Look how easy that syntax is in the above answer to order a list of players or to convert it to a dictionary. Its all right there and can be used with minimal effort. If you do not understand lamda syntax then go read up on that first before you start making poor design decisions. You will spend much less time learning how to use a Lambda than maintaining a poorly built application.